# How to add new entry to the user classpath in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add a new wizard, that creates new template class. When the class is been created, I need to add my own jar to the user classpath.
For example - I have "my-sdk.jar". When the user create new "MyOwnClass", I create a new class with my content. This content depends on my-sdk.jar, in order to compile.

How do i add this jar to the user classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JDT APIs to update an eclipse plugin classpath.

```
IProject project = ...;
IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
IClasspathEntry[] entries = javaProject.getRawClasspath();
IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[entries.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(entries, 0, newEntries, 0, entries.length);
// use Path and JavaCore to create a new entry
javaProject.setRawClasspath(newEntries, null);
```

See this [JDT Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html#jdt_classpath) for a more complete example.